# Database Problem sqlite3.Operational Error for Flask

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlite

Hey I am having trouble with this little project I am doing.

Basically, I am trying to structure a therapist and his patients. I have two models of the database, therapist and patient. Therapist signs up or logs-in, I have both a registration Form and a Login Form for the therapist.

After therapist successfully logs in or registers, it is led to the home page where he can click a link to register patients. I have already set a `patientregistrationform` as well.

I am having trouble with two things.

On my project once I run it, and I put in fields on the registration form to create a user/therapist, I get an error. I believe it is an error in the model class, but I can't figure out why.

I just started doing this a week ago, so, I really would appreciate it if someone could help me with this.

- `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: user [SQL: 'SELECT user.id AS user_id, user.username AS user_username, user.email AS user_email, user.password_hash AS user_password_hash \nFROM user \nWHERE user.username = ?\n LIMIT ? OFFSET ?'] [parameters: ('yohannes', 1, 0)] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)`

**This is my models file**

```
from app import db, login
from flask_login import UserMixin
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    patients = db.relationship('Patient', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {}>'.format(self.username)

    def set_password(self, password):
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def check_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)


@login.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.get(int(id))

class Patient(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(64))
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(64))
    dateofbirth = db.Column(db.String(32))
    typeoftherapy = db.Column(db.String(64))
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Patient {}>'.format(self.firstname)
```

**and this is my forms file**

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, BooleanField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import ValidationError, DataRequired, EqualTo, Email
from app.models import User, Patient

class PatientSignUpForm(FlaskForm):
    firstname = StringField('First Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    lastname = StringField('Last Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    dateofbirth = StringField('Date of Birth', validators=[DataRequired()])
    typeoftherapy = StringField('Type of Therapy', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Sign Up Patient')

class TherapistLoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    remember_me = BooleanField('Remember Me')
    submit = SubmitField('Sign In')

class TherapistRegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password2 = PasswordField(
        'Repeat Password', validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('password')])
    submit = SubmitField('Register')

    def validate_username(self, username):
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username.data).first()
        if user is not None:
            raise ValidationError('Please use a different username.')

    def validate_email(self, email):
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first()
        if user is not None:
            raise ValidationError('Please use a different email address.')
```

**This is my routes file**

```
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, request
from flask_login import login_user, logout_user, current_user, login_required
from werkzeug.urls import url_parse
from app import app, db
from app.forms import PatientSignUpForm, TherapistLoginForm, TherapistRegistrationForm
from app.models import Patient, User

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
@login_required

def index():
    patients = [
        {
            'doctor': {'username': 'Yohannes'},
            'treatment': 'Physical Therapy'
        },
        {
            'doctor': {'username': 'Henok'},
            'treatment': 'Mental Therapy'
        }

    ]
    return render_template('index.html', title ='Home', user=user, patients=patients)

@app.route('/patients')

def patients():
    patient = Patient.query.filter_by(firstname=firstname).all()
    patients = [
    {'Patient': patient}, {'Patient': patient}
    ]
    return render_template('base.html', patient=patient)


@app.route('/signup', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = TherapistLoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = Therapist.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if user is None or not Therapist.check_password(form.password.data):
            flash('Invalid username or password')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        login_user(user, remember=form.remember_me.data)
        next_page = request.args.get('next')
        if not next_page or url_parse(next_page).netloc != '':
            next_page = url_for('index')
        return redirect(next_page)
    return render_template('login.html', title='Sign In', form=form)

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = TherapistRegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User(username=form.username.data, email=form.email.data)
        user.set_password(form.password.data)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Congratulations, you are now a registered user!')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('register.html', title='Register', form=form)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error from sqlite3 is very good, it tells you `no such table: user` which means exactly what it says - there is no table in your database called `user`. Have you initialised your database? Do you have a database file?

I suggest you use [Flask-Migrate](https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for your database init and migrations.